# Как брать данные с БД с конца таблицы?

Tags: mysql

Как сделать так, чтобы данные с базы данных (с таблицы) брались с конца, а не сначала?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ORDER BY** - сортировать по, есть же у вас какое-то поле, где вы предполагаете, где начало, где конец.

Comment: можно по подробнее????для чяйника))

Comment: Вопрос очень размыт.
что означает брать данные с конца таблицы?

примерно можно реализовать так
есть таблица с такой структурой
Id integer (autoinc)
s varchar

так вот каждая запись S будет иметь свой ID вот понему и определяем какая запись первая какая последняя.

то есть запрос Вам нужен будет примерно такой

** SELECT S FROM TABLE ORDER BY -ID** на выходите будите иметь список записей в обратном (согластно Id) порядке.

Comment: Спасиба тебе!

Comment: Реляционная модель данных подразумевает, что данные не имеют естественного порядка строк. Т.е. порядок строк любого запроса определяется явным указанием ORDER BY либо результат непредсказуем

Comment: В БД таблицах нет начала и конца...

Answer (score 0):

Для сортировки записей по убыванию значения поля `ID` можно использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
SELECT * FROM <NAME_TABLE> ORDER BY ID DESC // ID по убыванию или наоборот ID ASС
```